# Capture result of dynamic T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to re-purpose the code available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-loops). Goal is to check all columns in all tables to count NULLs for quality check

I have `#tbl_chknull` holding all queries to be executed. To execute each query, I have:

```
DECLARE   @nbr_statements INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tbl_chknull)
        , @i INT = 1
        , @vi INT
        ;

WHILE   @i <= @nbr_statements
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql_code NVARCHAR(4000) = (SELECT sql_code FROM #tbl_chknull WHERE [sequence] = @i);
    EXEC sp_executesql 
          @Query  = @sql_code
        , @Params = N'@vi INT OUTPUT'
        , @vi = @vi OUTPUT;

    SELECT @vi
    SET     @i +=1;
END
```

The `EXEC statement` displays the value I want to be stored, however this doesn't seem to be captured in the `@vi OUTPUT` variable (which is always NULL in the `SELECT` part). Do you know what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Do a `PRINT @sql_code` to verify the query

Comment: Show one of this statements. I guess for are just not setting the `@vi` value there.

Comment: The outcome of this query depends on the contents of the `sql_code` column in the temp table `#tbl_chknull`.  Can you please provide a sample of the contents of the temp table?  Please also note that the document you link to is targeted at a specialist database product formerly knows as Azure SQL Data Warehouse now known as Azure Synapse Analytics and hence has some special considerations, eg the behaviour of temp tables is different in Synapse versus Azure SQL DB.  Can you confirm which particular Azure database product you are working with as Synapse (nee Warehouse) is not tagged? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Squirrel, @gotqn, @wBob -- so just a sample, the `@sql_code` in `#tbl_chknull` have valid sql statements like: `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [dbo].[RLF_KNORR_SKU] WHERE [product_code] IS NOT NULL;` and so produces two outputs: first from the `EXEC` part is 0, second from the `SELECT` part is NULL